# Do shadow people exist?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I always remember a rumor that in super Mario galaxy there was a level where you could see some shadow people just standing there and watching you.

Was this rumor actually true, if so on what level was it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shadow figures do exist and you can find them in the Shiverburn Galaxy in *Super Mario Galaxy 2*. You can find plenty of info on them online.

According to some websites they are visible on the *Prince Pikante's Peppery Mood* and *Octo-Army Icy Rainbow Romp* levels and they appear to be Kodamas, which are Japanese tree spirits.

Sources:

- [Gaming Myths wikia](http://gamingmyths.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_People_of_Hell_Valley)
- [Nintendo tech forums (this may be deleted at some point as it's not on-topic for them)](http://techforums.nintendo.com/message/62438)